# Template specialization vs. Compiler optimization

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class with a boolean template argument.

```
template<bool b>
class Foo {
  void doFoo();
};
```

I want `doFoo` to do different things based on the value of `b`.

Naively I could write

**Option 1**

```
template<bool b> void Foo<b>::doFoo() {
  if (b) cout << "hello";
  else cout << "goodbye";
}
```

This seems inefficient to me because I have to execute an `if` every time the function is called event though the correct branch should be known at compile time. I could fix this with template specialization:

**Option 2**

```
template<> void Foo<true>::doFoo() { cout << "hello"; }
template<> void Foo<false>::doFoo() { cout << "goodbye"; }
```

This way I don't have any conditionals executed in runtime. This solution is a bit more complicated (especially since in my real code the class has several template arguments and you can't partially specialize functions so I will need to wrap the function in a class).

My question is, is the compiler smart enough to know not to execute the conditional in option 1 since it always executes the same way or do I need to write the specializations? If the compiler is smart enough I would be happy to know if this is compiler dependent or a language feature that I can rely on?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The compiler will probably optimize the branch away since it is known at compile time what `b` is. This is not guaranteed though and the only way to know for sure is to check the assembly.

If you can use C++17 you can use [`if constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) and that guarantees only one branch will exist.

Comment: That's cool thanks, I hadn't heard of that. I hope I can use it :)

Comment: If a compiler with any optimization flag doesn't optimize the branch away, I'd file a bug. :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Totally.  I guess that means we need to file a bug report with MSVS as it is the only one in the "big 3" that compiles both branches with no optimizations: https://godbolt.org/g/fgcwqD

Comment: It is to note that this is obviously optimized in release mode: https://godbolt.org/g/KZPMgd

Comment: Notice that if the thing you want to do along the `if (b)` branch *would be ill-formed when `!b`*, then you will *need* to use `if constexpr (b)` or put it into a template specialization, to prevent the compiler from trying to compile it when `!b`. If that's not a concern (e.g., in your example), personally I'd stick with `if (b)` for clarity, or `if constexpr (b)` if I was in a C++17-only world. I'd trust the optimizer to do the right thing here. (Others' answers and comments give empirical evidence that mainstream optimizers are indeed worthy of that trust.)

Answer (score 5):

> This seems inefficient to me because I have to execute an if every time the function is called

The compiler will *probably* optimize this away - but it's not guaranteed by the standard. To be certain, you should look at the output of the compiler you care about (with the compile options you plan to use): eg. clang doesn't have a branch in the linked [example](https://godbolt.org/g/NXQU9P) (the un-optimized version has lots of function call boilerplate but no branch).

In C++17 you can use [`if constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if), and the branch not taken will be discarded at compile time.

Comment: This is not as elegant as the other answer, but it's not incorrect as far as I can tell. +1.

Comment: @Bathsheba What do you mean "not as elegant"? It's (almost) the same answer.

Comment: Even I think Nathan's answer looks nicer, but they're so similar I'm not going to spend any time polishing my prose.